# Simple way to launch a script on a remote computer from android device

Tags: macos, android, remote-control

I have a certain script on a desktop/laptop computer (running OS X, but ideally the solution should be cross platform) that I need to trigger remotely from an Android device. I do not want to open up the computer directly to incoming requests from the Internet (the IP is dynamic, I don't wish to use something like dyndns, and I don't want to depend on port forwarding from the router).

What is some simple/elegant way (that doesn't require any non-free software) to trigger such a remote script, from an Android device, with just one or two taps?

Comment: This is either an Android question or an OS X question, depending on how you look at it, but it looks more like an Android Enthusiasts Q&A question to me for 2 reasons: 1. You want to trigger a remote script from an Android device. 2. You also have an account at Android Enthusiasts Q&A, so all you have to do is copy/paste this question to there.

Comment: @karel the solution may very well be completely agnostic to the platform of the device from which the initial signal is sent from. E.g. it may involve loading a URL, not some native android app